# Stack overflow with no recursion?

Tags: c++, lexer

As far as I can see, my code has no recursion, but I am getting exception 0xC00000FD. According to Rider For Unreal Engine, it is happening in the main function. It's being encountered at the decompiled code

```
mov byte ptr [r11], 0x0
```

It was working fine, then suddenly when I ran it a second time, just to make sure it worked, it broke. It now gives that exception every time.
Here is my code:

```cpp
// Language.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>


#include "Lexer/Lexer.h"
#include "Util/StrUtil.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string line, fileString;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1]);
    
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        int lines = 0;
        
        while(file.good())
        {
            if (lines > 10000)
            {
                std::cerr << "Whoa there, that file's a little long! Try compiling something less than 10,000 lines." << '\n';
                return -1;
            }
            getline(file, line);
            fileString += line + (char)10;
            lines++;
        }
    }

    fileString += (char)0x00;

    std::string arr[10000];
    int arrLength = StrUtil::split(fileString, "\n", arr);

    Line lines[10000];
    Lexer::lex(arr, arrLength, lines);
    
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// Lexer.cpp
#include "Lexer.h"

void Lexer::lex(std::string (&str)[10000], int length, Line (&lines)[10000])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        
    }
}
```

```cpp
// StrUtil.cpp
#include "StrUtil.h"


#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

int StrUtil::split(std::string str, std::string delimiter, std::string (&out)[10000])
{
    int pos = 0;
    out[0] = str;
    while (out[pos].find(delimiter) != std::string::npos)
    {
        const size_t found = out[pos].find(delimiter);
        out[pos + 1] = out[pos].substr(found + delimiter.length());
        out[pos] = out[pos].substr(0, found);
        pos++;
    }

    return pos + 2;
}
```

For custom types, `Line` is an array of `Token`s, which are just <`TokenType`, `std::string`> pairs.

Comment: `std::string arr[10000];Line lines[10000];` -- Stack blows up.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do you mean it runs out of memory?

Comment: @LysanderMealy What is a stack overflow except the stack running out of memory?

Comment: @LysanderMealy I guess it's time to learn to use `std::vector`,

Comment: Remember on windows the default stack size is 1 MB.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `std::ifstream file; file.open(argv[1]);` to `std::ifstream file(argv[1]);`.

Comment: Incidentally, `(char)0x00` is usually written `'\0'`. And `(char)10` is unusual; if that's supposed to insert a newline, write it as `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I can see, my code has no recursion

Indeed, there is no recursion in the shown code. Lack of recursion doesn't mean that you won't overflow the stack.

> Stack overflow with no recursion?

Yes, this program is likely going to overflow the stack on some systems.

> ```
> std::string arr[10000];
> ```

Typical size of `std::string` is 32 bytes (can vary greatly between language implementations). 10000 strings is 312 kiB. The execution stack on most desktop systems is one to few MiB. That one array is about the third of the memory that has to fit all of the automatic variables at the deepest stack frame of the program. It is very feasible that the remaning stack memory isn't enough for the rest of the program, especially considering you have another huge array of `Line` objects.

To fix the program, do not allocate massive variables such as this in automatic storage.